# bootstrap pagination control's alignment to be the same

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating bootstrap pager using below code.

```
<style>
.navigation-bar .pagination {
    margin-top: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="navigation-bar">
<span class="pull-left"><strong>Total record(s) 1000</strong></span>                                    
<ul class="pagination pull-right">                                        
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;Search</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!--<a style="padding: 0; margin: 0; margin-top: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;"><div ddl-record-filter-count>Filter By</div></a>-->
        <a style="padding: 6px;"><div>Filter By<select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select></div></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span>&nbsp;First</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>&nbsp;Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span></span>&nbsp;1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span></span>&nbsp;2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span></span>&nbsp;3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>&nbsp;Next</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span>&nbsp;Last</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Problem is drop-down control is not in the same height with others.

[image]

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q60rucAKsLIqcF6a1iJ0?p=preview)

Please let me get your suggestion.

### To see detail of my problem , please use chrome and zoom to 110%

[image]

Comment: In your Plunker you have `style="padding: 0px;"` in the filter selector, which makes it look like above screenshot. But in your code you have `style="padding: 6px;"` - when I enter that in your Plunker it looks good to me.

Comment: Also, when you remove the whole style from the `<a>` tag it looks okay.

Comment: @McVenco, did you try using zoom in and out feature of your browser ?

Comment: When I remove the styling, or enter `padding: 6px;`, I get this result when zooming in: http://imgur.com/umJ59xG (using Google Chrome)
Can you perhaps make it more clear what it is that you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: This is just the way that the browser renders the page on different zoom levels. Firefox renders it differently than Chrome on different zoom levels as well, so it would probably be a tough (if not impossible) problem to tackle.

Is there a reason you are looking at different zoom levels while developing your page, or is this just something you stumbled upon while zooming? In the latter case I wouldn't really be bothered about it...

Comment: I think applying height to .pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span can solve your problem if your content are sure that your content height will not be increased.

Answer (score 0):

used to this style

```
.pagination.pull-right > li:nth-of-type(2) > a{float:left;line-height:32px;}
```

Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
 .navigation-bar .pagination {
  margin-top: 0;
 }
 .pagination.pull-right > li:nth-of-type(2) > a{float:left;line-height:32px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navigation-bar">
 <span class="pull-left"><strong>Total record(s) 1000</strong></span>                                    
 <ul class="pagination pull-right">                                        
  <li>
   <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;Search</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <!--<a style="padding: 0; margin: 0; margin-top: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;"><div ddl-record-filter-count>Filter By</div></a>-->
   <a style="padding: 0px;"><div>Filter By<select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select></div></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span>&nbsp;First</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>&nbsp;Previous</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"><span></span>&nbsp;1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"><span></span>&nbsp;2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"><span></span>&nbsp;3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>&nbsp;Next</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span>&nbsp;Last</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make it zoom in and out using mouse wheel and then you will see it still has alignment are not in the same with others issue.